# How to get rid of Permission denied (publickey) error on running bundle exec foreman start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, foreman

Whenever I run `bundle exec foreman start` I am getting below error.

[image]

It was working fine till now, but it stopped working suddenly.

**Procfile**

> web: bundle exec rails s -p 3000
>
> redis: redis-server --port 6379
>
> db: /usr/local/bin/mysqld --gdb
>
> watch_re: npm run watch:js:re
>
> watch_vue: npm run watch:js:vue
>
> sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -q high -q default -q crawler_facebook -q
>   crawler_twitter -q mckinley -q twitter_io -q twitter_reach_freq -q
>   master_update -q twitter_check_notification -q tw_report_file_creator
>   -q mojaco_tw_crawler -q mojaco_fb_crawler -q fb_report_file_creator -q cache_manager -q facebook_attribution
>
> ssh_tunneling_for_elasticache: ssh -N -L
>   60660:sherpa-production.y6mej4.0001.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com:60660
>   ec2-user@ec2-13-114-37-187.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com -o
>   "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null"

Comment: Please copy+paste your Procfile here. One of the commands that is running tries to connect to an AWS (ElasticCache does that) and the AWS instance does not know about your public SSH key. You will have to add it to the server in order to properly connect via SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your public SSH-key is unknown to the AWS-server.

```
ssh_tunneling_for_elasticache: ssh -N -L 60660:sherpa-production.y6mej4.0001.apne1.cache.amazonaws.com:60660 ec2-user@ec2-13-114-37-187.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null"
```

This command tries to build up a tunneling connection to the AWS.
Here's how to setup the server with your public key if you can access it via the command line:

1. Generate your key if you haven't already (on your local device):
   `ssh-keygen`
2. Paste the key to the servers authorized-keys file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

---

Considering you have no access to the AWS other than through the web console, do the following as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingMindTerm):

> Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
>
> Select your instance. In the Description tab, verify the value of Key
>   pair name.
>
> If you did not specify a key pair when you launched the instance, you
>   can terminate the instance and launch a new instance, ensuring that
>   you specify a key pair. If this is an instance that you have been
>   using but you no longer have the .pem file for your key pair, you can
>   replace the key pair with a new one. For more information, see
>   Connecting to Your Linux Instance if You Lose Your Private Key.